# Is it necessary to use Timthumb in Wordpress 2.9+?

Tags: wordpress, post

as Wordpress 2.9 comes with built in post thumbnail features, is it necessary to use Timthumb ?

Comment: You might try asking this question on the WordPress site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. You will likely get a much quicker response there.

Answer (score 2):

#### With post thumbnails don't have the ability to dynamically crop and zoom images.

Another solution is to use Justin Tadlock's [Get The Image Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/).  The Plugin tries to use `the_post_thumbnail()` wherever possible and gives you full control of sizing cropping and displaying images.  It also allows you to grab images by custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary, but many WordPress themes and plug-ins still use it.

If you don't use any of those, then you don't have to have/install/use TimThumb. If you do, then you are likely to have issues without it because most of those themes and plug-ins are overriding the default functionality deliberately, or are not passing along images in a way that WordPress' default thumbnail feature knows about it.